# Follow mouse position with div (jQuery) - issue when scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, cursor, mousemove

I've created a custom svg #cursor that follows my mouse position with jQuery (replacing the cursor using css limits the image size to 32px and looks pixelated on Retina, so I want to stick with using jQuery).

ISSUE: when the user scrolls, the cursor does not move which creates a jerky effect: https://jsfiddle.net/jhhbrook/ucuLefut/

I want my svg cursor to follow smoothly. How can I do this?

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
$("#cursor").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not better use CSS cursor property itself?.As far as i know it's impossible to get cursor position without any mouse-event

```
 body {
 cursor:url(http://mayadufeu.github.io/img/cursor-auto.svg), auto;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0chzmhrd/

**UPDATE**:I think you can get mouse coordinates by using the code below but no clue how to animate the cursor nicely as the scroll event updates position in steps and not in continuous values.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {cursor:none;}
#content {height: 1200px;}
#cursor {position: absolute;}
#counter {position:fixed;margin:1px 0px 0px 100px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="counter">counter</p>
<img id="cursor" src="http://mayadufeu.github.io/img/cursor-auto.svg"/>
<div id="content">
  content
</div>

</body>  
<script type="text/javascript">
var a;var b;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      a = e.pageX;
      b = e.pageY;
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#cursor").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    $('#counter').text('Mouse -> X : '+a+ '  ' + 'Y: '+b);
  });

  $(document).scroll(function (e) { 
    $('#counter').text('Mouse -> X : '+a+ '  ' + 'Y: '+b);
    //can animate here
  });

});
</script>
</html>
```

Unfortunately doesn't run on JSfiddle idk why so  try it out in a HTML file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but as I mentioned in the post replacing the cursor using css looks pixelated on Retina displays compared to the jQuery option

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and in this other thread there's the SOLUTION:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58807531/11455013

It worked for me, all that matters is putting **clientX and clientY** instead of pageX and pageY:

```
$("#cursor").css({left:e.clientX, top:e.clientY});
```

AND in css, set #cursor to have **position fixed** instead of absolute

```
#cursor {position: fixed; width: 20px; height: 20px; transform: translate(-10px, -10px); }
```

Here I put the translation to have the mouse in the center of #cursor div, but for this there can be other solutions of course.