# Element following mouse movement and scroll

Tags: javascript, css, mousemove

I'm trying to write a bit of Vanilla Javascript to make an element follow my mouse movements. I've used clientX, clientY and the mousemove event to make it follow, but when I scroll the page the element doesn't move with the mouse. I thought maybe I'd need to use the scroll event but I'm struggling to make it work. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const mouseFollow = document.getElementById('mouse-follow');
    const x = e.clientX - 25; //-25 to center div over mouse
    const y = e.clientY - 25; 

    mouseFollow.style.top = `${y}px`;
    mouseFollow.style.left = `${x}px`;
})
```

Answer (score 6):

- Use `position: fixed;`. `clientX/Y` is relative to the viewport, so is CSS position `fixed`.
- Cache your selector, there's no need to query the DOM for an element on every mouse move

```js
const elPointer  = document.querySelector("#pointer");

addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
  elPointer.style.cssText = `
    left: ${evt.clientX}px;
    top:  ${evt.clientY}px;
  `;
});
```

```css
body { /* DEMO scrollbars */ min-height: 200vh; }

#pointer {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f0b;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="pointer"></div>
```

Another nice way is to use JS's [style.setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) and change the value to CSS vars like:

```js
const elPointer = document.querySelector("#pointer");

addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
  elPointer.style.setProperty("--x", evt.clientX);
  elPointer.style.setProperty("--y", evt.clientY);
});
```

```css
body { /* DEMO scrollbars */ min-height: 200vh; }

#pointer {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f0b;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  left: calc(var(--x) * 1px);
  top: calc(var(--y) * 1px);
}
```

```html
<div id="pointer"></div>
```

Comment: Great this works, I was using position absolute. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO @psshaw20.

I suspect the thing you are missing is that the element must have an absolute position. Here is a working solution:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {

   const mouseFollow = document.getElementById('mouse-follow');
   const x = e.clientX - 25; //-25 to center div over mouse
   const y = e.clientY - 25; 
   console.log(x);
    
   mouseFollow.style.top = `${y}px`;
   mouseFollow.style.left = `${x}px`;
})
```

```css
#mouse-follow{
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<span id=mouse-follow>*</span>
```

Comment: Doesn't work if page scrolled.