# Custom cursor doesn't move with page when scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a custom cursor, but im having an issue with its position when you scroll the page. Rather than following the mouse cursor, it stays where it was on the page until you move the mouse again and then it catches up.

```js
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cursor);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => mouseCursor.style.display = 'block');
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => mouseCursor.style.display = 'none');


if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      jQuery('.cursor').remove();
    } else {
      mouseCursor.style.display = 'block';
    }

function cursor(e){

    mouseCursor.style.top = "calc(" +e.pageY + "px - 1rem)";
    mouseCursor.style.left = "calc(" +e.pageX + "px - 1rem)";
}
```

```css
.section{
height:200vh;
}


.cursor{
    display:none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    outline: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition-property: background, transform;
    transform-origin: center center;
    z-index: 20000;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>

<div class="section"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element following mouse movement and scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807504/element-following-mouse-movement-and-scroll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work with `clientX/Y` property not `pageX/Y`.
Because `clientX/Y` coordinates are relative to the top left corner of the visible part of the page, while `pageX/Y` is relative to the top left corner of the whole page.

Also, Instead of making your circle `position:absolute` , you have to change it to `position:fixed;`

> Elements with fixed positioning are fixed with respect to the viewport

[CSS absolute and fixed positioning](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning?source=post_pageg=AOvVaw0ORhZSF84Iqz7s-GWgomKW)

```js
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', cursor);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => mouseCursor.style.display = 'block');
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => mouseCursor.style.display = 'none');


if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      jQuery('.cursor').remove();
    } else {
      mouseCursor.style.display = 'block';
    }

function cursor(e){

    mouseCursor.style.top = "calc(" +e.clientY + "px - 1rem)";
    mouseCursor.style.left = "calc(" +e.clientX + "px - 1rem)";
}
```

```css
.section{
height:200vh;
}


.cursor{
    display:none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
    outline: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition-property: background, transform;
    transform-origin: center center;
    z-index: 20000;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>

<div class="section"></div>
```